# Как изменить логику кода для того, чтобы сделать парсинг работоспособным?

Tags: php, парсер

уважаемое сообщество.

Есть код:

```
    <?php
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

function curlGetPage($url, $referer = 'https://google.com/')
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
return $response;
}

$url = 'https://s.ua/smartfony-apple-iphone/';
$page = curlGetPage($url);
$html = str_get_html($page);

$pagenavi = $html->find('*[class="pager__container"]', 0);
$lastSicounter = $pagenavi->find('*[class="pager__item j-catalog-pagination-btn"]', -1);

if ($lastSicounter->hasAttribute('href')) {
$lastHref = $lastSicounter->getAttribute('href');
$pattern = '/page=(\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $lastHref, $matches);
$pageNumber = intval($matches[1]);
$schetchik = $pageNumber;

echo "Total pages to parse: " . $schetchik . "\n";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $schetchik; $i++) {
$pageUrl = "https://s.ua/smartfony-apple-iphone/filter/page=$i";
$pageContent = curlGetPage($pageUrl);
$pageHtml = str_get_html($pageContent);
echo "Parsing page: " . $pageUrl . "\n";

foreach ($pageHtml->find('*[class="catalogCard-main-b"]') as $element) {
$img = $element->find('img.catalogCard-img', 0);
$link = $element->find('a.catalogCard-image', 0);
$priceElem = $element->find('*[class="catalogCard-price"]', 0);

$imgSrc = $img->src;
$productTitle = $img->alt;
$productLink = $link->href;
$price = ltrim($priceElem->plaintext, "$");

// Далее вы можете использовать найденные данные, например, добавить их в базу данных или вывести на экран.
echo "Product: " . $productTitle . "\n";
echo "Image URL: " . $imgSrc . "\n";
echo "Product Link: " . $productLink . "\n";
echo "Price: " . $price . "\n";

echo "------------------------\n";
}

usleep(1500000);

// Опционально, вы можете добавить лимит на количество страниц для парсинга.
 if ($i > 100) {
    break;
 }
}
} else {
echo "Last link not found or doesn't have the 'href' attribute.";
}
?>

.....
```

Он просто проходит 12 итераций цикла for при этом не добравшись до блока кода с циклом `foreach()`.
Подозреваю что причина в том что эти объекты содержат одинаковые значения с первой страницы сайта и сразу же передаются во второй цикл. Но я менял названия этих переменных и не могу понять в чем причина того, что интерпретатор так выполняет код. Проверяю его на консоли phpstorm.

```
$url = 'https://s.ua/smartfony-apple-iphone/';
$page = curlGetPage($url);
$html = str_get_html($page);
```

Как исправить код так, чтобы сам скрипт выполнялся на сервере вначале на первой странице. Потом на всех остальных страницах категории.